# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Debtor with id=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, mongoid, rails-postgresql

I recently converted a project from MongoDB/mongoid to PostgreSQL.  After the transition, all of my model specs are passing and I have most controller specs passing.  Three of my controllers are not passing tests though.

The Alert, Order, and User models are dependent on the Client and Debtor Models per the below model definitions:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, autosave: true, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :alerts, autosave: true, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :orders, autosave: true, dependent: :destroy

  ...
end

class Debtor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders, autosave: true
  has_many :alerts, autosave: true

  ...
end

class Alert < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
  belongs_to :debtor

  ...
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :debtor

  ...
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  rolify

  devise :database_authenticatable, 
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles, :join_table => :users_roles
  belongs_to :client
  has_many :orders
end
```

Almost all of the failed tests have the same error (some have "Couldn't find Client with id= "):

```
 129) OrdersController logged in as a regular user GET #new renders the new template
 Failure/Error: get :new, client_id: @user.client_id
 ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
   Couldn't find Debtor with id=
 # ./spec/controllers/orders_controller_spec.rb:59:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I have ran db:test:prepare and the drop, create, migrate sequence.

Update: Here's the related spec from orders_controller_spec.rb and the related controller.  I'm a rspec noob, so I'll apologize now if the `before(:each)` block is a crime against humanity.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe OrdersController do
  before (:each) do
    @user, @user2, @user3, @admin = FactoryGirl.create(:user), FactoryGirl.create(:user), FactoryGirl.create(:user), FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    @client, @client2 = FactoryGirl.create(:client), FactoryGirl.create(:client)
    @debtor, @debtor2, @debtor3 = FactoryGirl.create(:debtor), FactoryGirl.create(:debtor), FactoryGirl.create(:debtor)
    @order, @order2, @order3, @order4 = FactoryGirl.create(:order), FactoryGirl.create(:order), FactoryGirl.create(:order),FactoryGirl.create(:order)
    @role = FactoryGirl.create(:role)
    @admin_role = FactoryGirl.create(:admin_role)
    @vip_role = FactoryGirl.create(:vip_role)
    @user.roles << @role
    @user2.roles << @vip_role
    @user3.roles << @role
    @admin.roles << @admin_role
    @client.users << @user << @admin
    @client.orders << @order << @order2
    @client2.users << @user2 << @user3
    @client2.orders << @order3 << @order4
  end

  context "logged in as a regular user" do
    before { sign_in @user }

    describe "GET #index" do
      before { get :index, client_id: @user.client_id }

      it "assigns a list of orders belonging to user client" do
        assigns(:orders).to_a.should eq([@order, @order2])
      end
      it "renders the :index template" do
        response.should render_template :index, client_id: @user.client_id
      end
    end

    describe "GET #show" do
      context "for order belonging to user client" do
        before { get :show, client_id: @user.client_id, id: @order }

        it "assigns the requested order to @order" do
          assigns(:order).should eq(@order)
        end
        it "renders the :show template" do
          response.should render_template :show, client_id: @user.client_id, id: @order
        end
      end

      context "for order not belonging to user client" do
        before { get :show, client_id: @client2.id, id: @order3 }

        it "redirects to the home view" do
          response.should redirect_to root_url
        end
      end 
    end

    describe "GET #new" do
      it "renders the new template" do
        get :new, client_id: @user.client_id
        response.should render_template :new, client_id: @user.client_id
      end
    end

    ...
  end
end
```

The related controller actions:

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  before_filter :load_client
  before_filter :has_enough_units, :only => [:create]
  respond_to :html
  load_and_authorize_resource :debtor
  load_and_authorize_resource :order, :through => :client, :shallow => true

  def index
    if @client == nil
      @orders = Order.all
    else
      @orders = @client.orders.all
    end
    respond_with(@orders)
  end

  def show
    if @client == nil
      @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    else
      @order = @client.orders.find(params[:id])
    end
  end

  def new
    if current_user.has_role? :admin
      @order = Order.new
    else
      @order = @client.orders.build
    end
    @order.build_debtor
    @clients = Client.all.to_a
  end

  ...
end
```

Hopefully this is enough information...

Comment: You should also show what happens in your specs and in your controller. That's where the error happens.

Comment: I added parts of the spec and controller.  I didn't everything just to cut down on the volume of code, but I can post more if needed.